# How do I make my default (or any static) route permanent on Linux (Fedora 9 specifically)?

Tags: linux, installation, default, fedora, routes

I've just performed a new installation of the very latest (Fall, 2008) version of Fedora 9 Linux and am perplexed that it never set the default route properly and that even traveling the labyrinthine ways of this OS, there's no obvious way.

Of course, it's clear that one can do it on a one-off basis like this:

```
   route add default gw gw1 metric 0 eth0
```

or like this:

```
   ip route add to default via 192.168.2.1 protocol static
```

However, neither of these survives reboot. In reading through /etc/rc.d/init.d/network, it attempts to find data from a file in /etc/sysconfig/static-routes, but that file never existed. So, I tried to create it and populate it with data. The trouble with that is that the script places a dash (minus sign) in an odd spot that I'm not sure how to deal with.

Of course, one can just edit /etc/rc.d/init.d/network, but that would be non-standard. As it is, my only other recourse seems to be editing rc.local, but that doesn't come early enough in the boot sequence to be there for things like, for example, the network time daemon.

I've done my homework - I've read all the man pages, info entries, tried apropos, and I've even done a fair bit of web searching, all to no avail - my next step, sans answer here, will be to sign up to the Fedora mailing lists and ask there! Or, give up and edit the scripts.

So, how is one supposed to do this?

Comment: What's in your /etc/sysconfig/network and /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-scripts files?

Comment: Paul, network has an entry for GATEWAY, and it's correct. There's an entry for IPV6_DEFAULTGW which is blank. network-scripts doesn't have a subdirectory or file named network-scripts, but there are a _lot_ of scripts there! One is called ifup-routes and it only take a device; this it? -shrug-

Comment: Sorry, I mean /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0, not /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-scripts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The gateway is normally set in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0, not in /etc/sysconfig/network.  For example, on my current machine:

> /etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
HOSTNAME=flyboys
NISDOMAIN=ekcineon
```

> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=00:1d:09:31:3a:cc
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=150.102.65.30
GATEWAY=150.102.65.252
TYPE=Ethernet
```

Note that I set HWADDR because I have two ethernet cards and I want to make sure the right one is assigned to eth0.  The configuration for the second card is in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1

Comment: Thanks, Paul. The answer is: put your gateway line in the appropriate interface's script in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ - just as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used recent versions of Fedora, but it was often set as a GATEWAY variable in /etc/sysconfig/network.

Of course, if you just wanted it to work, you could just put the commands in /etc/rc.local to be executed when the boot sequence completes.

Comment: GATEWAY is usually in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0, not in /etc/sysconfig/network.

Comment: Paul, zigdon was right, there is a GATEWAY entry, but it was there all along and apparently was ineffective.

Comment: I've usually just bodged this into /etc/rc.local when I've needed to set up multiple static routes; as long as you don't have any services that rely on that route early on (like an nfs mount), it may be the most expedient solution.

Comment: As I wrote in my original question, rc.local is way late.

Answer (score 1):

just edit the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ethXX`

and write inside: **default via ip_address dev device** , replace **ip_address** with **your gateway ip** and **device** with **the name of the right eth device**. but for the **Device option** its ... optional, set it in the case of multiple eth devices.
Works even in case of network restart, the route directive in rc.local works at boot only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nmcli if available, e.i.

```
# nmcli con show
NAME         UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
System eth0  xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  ethernet  eth0
ens33        xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  ethernet  --

# nmcli con edit "System eth0"

nmcli> goto ipv4
You may edit the following properties: method, dns, dns-search, dns-options, dns-priority, addresses, gateway, routes, route-metric, route-table, routing-rules, ignore-auto-routes, ignore-auto-dns, dhcp-client-id, dhcp-timeout, dhcp-send-hostname, dhcp-hostname, dhcp-fqdn, never-default, may-fail, dad-timeout
nmcli ipv4>

nmcli ipv4> print
['ipv4' setting values]
ipv4.method:                            manual
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         10.10.10.1/26
ipv4.gateway:                           10.10.10.129
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
nmcli ipv4>


nmcli ipv4> set routes 192.168.122.0/24 10.10.10.1

nmcli ipv4> verify
Verify setting 'ipv4': OK
nmcli ipv4> save
nmcli ipv4> quit

#nmcli con up "System eth0"
```

And it should create file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/routes- with proper parameters, e.g.

```
ADDRESS0=192.0.2.0
NETMASK0=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY0=198.51.100.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is for RHEL, as it is slightly different:

1. Identify the interface by using ifconfig
2. sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ethXX
3. add the routes as per syntax below, where /xx represents subnet mask

> ```
> host: 172.30.xxx.xxx via 172.30.xxx.xxx
> network: 172.30.xxx.xxx/xx via 172.30.xxx.xxx
> Default gateway: 0.0.0.0 via xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</li>
> ```
>
> Save the file.
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/network restart (Warning: if you forget to set
>   correct routes for the management interface (if applicable) you may lose
>   connectivity to the server)

Answer (score -1):

Haven't seen Fedora. But shouldn't there be some GUI for this kind of thing? If you have Gnome try running `gnome-network-preferences`

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.